# Could somebody explain how to use TYPE_INPUT_METHOD_DIALOG?

Tags: android, dialog, android-input-method

I want to create a simple dialog box (e.g. `EditText` and a button) when I press a key of the softkeyboard.

[WindowManager.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_INPUT_METHOD)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a dialog, you don't have to use WindowManager at all. Android developers have [an article on working with dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). `TYPE_INPUT_METHOD_DIALOG`, as the name suggests, is used for input methods (e.g. on-screen keyboards).

Comment: but the problem is that Dialog needs Activity to be extended.

Comment: "A dialog is always created and displayed as a part of an Activity. You should normally create dialogs from within your Activity's onCreateDialog(int) callback method. "
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: My service needs to extend InputMethodService. But If I want to create dialog, I need to extend Activity.

Comment: You're right, you can't create a dialog in a service. You should show a notification that a service needs attention, and when a user clicks it, you should bring up an activity with the needed dialog. Your initial question is somewhat confusing, the title has a question about WindowManager, the text has a question about creating a dialog, and now you're talking about user interaction in a service.

Comment: Thanks alot! now I am able to bring up an activity to accept the user input. Afterthat I want to pass the data back to the InputMethodService. Is it possible? I have used "intent" to pass the data. However, there were some difficulties when i tried to retrieve the "intent" and data in the InputMethodService.

Answer (score 0):

Per [hackbod](https://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-developers/124hx56xcc/how-to-use-type-input-method-dialog-to-show-dialog-from-an-ime) (chief Android developer), you don't want `TYPE_INPUT_METHOD_DIALOG`. You want `TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL`. This code should work. `myInputMethodView` should be any view currently displayed in your main input method window.

```
final Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
final Window w = d.getWindow();
final WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = w.getAttributes();
attrs.type = TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL;
attrs.token = myInputMethodView.getWindowToken();
w.setAttributes(attrs);
d.show();
```